# $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on the set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on the set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ . The question asks that whether $cl(f(C)) \subseteq f(cl(C))$. ($cl$ indicates closure). I think this is true but am stuck at how to prove it...

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x) = e^x$ and $C = \mathbb R$. Then

$$cl(f(C)) = [0,\infty),\ \ f(cl(C)) = (0,\infty).$$